# How to display row count at each row by group in JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to make JqGrid display row count at each row?
For example:

```
Group A

1 xxx xxx xxx

2 xxx xxx xxx

Group B

1 xxx xxx xxx

2 xxx xxx xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I not sure jqGrid support or not, but i already adjust the plugin to support what i want

For those who wish to have this too, can try these step:

1) Enable the rownumbers function for grouping

```
if (p.grouping === true) {
    p.scroll = false;
    // p.rownumbers = false;  <-- comment it
   ...
```

2) Calculate the row number

-After p.lastSelectedData = query.select(); add below code

```
if (p.rownumbers && p.grouping && p.groupingView.groupField.length > 0){
    var lastGroupVal = {};
    var custGroupCount = 0;
    var groupColName = '';
    for(var custCount=0; custCount<p.groupingView.groupField.length; custCount++){
        groupColName = p.groupingView.groupField[custCount];
        lastGroupVal[groupColName] = '';
    }

    for (j = 0; j < total; j++) {
        custGroupCount ++;
        for(var custCount=0; custCount<p.groupingView.groupField.length; custCount++){
            groupColName = p.groupingView.groupField[custCount];
            if(lastGroupVal[groupColName] != p.lastSelectedData[j][groupColName]){
                custGroupCount = 1;
                lastGroupVal[groupColName] = p.lastSelectedData[j][groupColName];
            }
        }
        p.lastSelectedData[j]['custGroupCount'] = custGroupCount;
    }
}
```

- This will calculate each row count and asign into 'custGroupCount'
  field
- Assign value into lastSelectedData is because i saw it is use this
  variable to display the data

3) Make the row number use 'custGroupCount' to display

-In addRowNum function, after assign value to 'v', add

```
if (p.grouping && p.groupingView.groupField.length > 0){
    v = p.lastSelectedData[(v-1)]['custGroupCount'];
}
```

ps: I use jqGrid to display data only, so not sure this changes will cause other problem or not

Output:
[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guXcS.png)